# Validating request in WCF - simple field

Tags: c#, wcf

How to force sending some field in my model ?
I have a following field:

```
[DataContract(IsRequired=true)]
double x;
```

However, when I don't define in `xml` request field `x` it assigns `x=0`.  I would like to get effect `Bad Request`.   How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use [Range] attribute someting like this

[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to force `>=1`, so something like `Range(1,infty)` ?